# Why the AJAX response is not returned from PHP side

Tags: php, ajax, multithreading

I am trying to get the PHP threads progress via AJAX, but the strange think I am facing right now is that any code before [`startPool()`](https://github.com/byjg/phpthread/) method can be seen in the AJAX response but not after it, would you explain to me why this is happening?

AjaxIndex.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta name="description" content="Source code generated using layoutit.com">
    <meta name="author" content="LayoutIt!">

    
    
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
        .error {
            border: 5px solid red !important;
        }
        
        .download-link {
            color: #26c605;
        }
        
        .download-error {
            color: #f20404;
        }
        
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form id="county-form" role="form" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="form-group">
                     
                    <label for="courtHouse">
                        Choose an action to scrap:
                    </label>
                    <select id="courtHouse" name="get-data" class="form-control">
                        <option value="none"></option>
                        <option value="all" selected="selected">Scrap.</option>
                        <option value="force">Force scrap.</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                
                <button id="scrape-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Scrap now
                </button>
                <p id="result"></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            let result_label = $("p#result");

            $("button#scrape-button").on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                
                result_label.removeClass('download-error').html('');
                
                if($('#courtHouse option:selected').text() === '') {
                    $("#courtHouse").css("border", "2px solid red");
                    $("#courtHouse").focus();
                    return;
                }
                
                $("#courtHouse").css("border", "0.916667px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)");
                $("#courtHouse").focus();
                
                result_label.html('<b>Please don\'t close the browser until the link appears here.</b>');
                const formData2 = $("#county-form").serialize();
                let last_response = '';
                $.ajax({
                    //url: "testAJAX.php",
                    url: "AjaxThread.php",
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: formData2,
                    dataType: 'text',
                    //contentType: 'application/json',
                    encode: true,
                    xhrFields: {
                        onprogress: function(e) {
                            let response = e.target.response.replace(/\n/g, '').split("|").slice(0, -1).pop();
                            //console.log('response split: ', e.target.response.replace(/\n/g, '').split("|").slice(0, -1));
                            console.log('response pop: ', response);
                            //console.log('response pop: ', JSON.parse(response).replace(/\n/g, ''));
                        }
                    },
                    success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                        console.log('success step');
                        console.log(result.status);
                        if(result.status === 'success') {
                            result_label.html(result.data);
                        }
                        else {
                            result_label.removeClass('download-link').addClass('download-error').html(result.data);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(request, status, error) {
                        result_label.removeClass('download-link').addClass('download-error').html('Internal error, please contact the support.');
                        console.log('error step');
                        //console.log(JSON.stringify(request));
                        console.log(request);
                        console.log(status);
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
                
                
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

AjaxThread.php:

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


    use \ByJG\PHPThread\ThreadPool as ScrapperPool;

    try {
        $scrapper_pool = new ScrapperPool();
        for($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
                $rfc_scrapper = new ScrapperThread($i);
                $scrap = function(ScrapperThread $instance) { 
                    return $instance->scrap(); 
                };
                $scrapper_pool->queueWorker($scrap, [$rfc_scrapper]);
        }

        $scrapper_pool->startPool();
        $scrapper_pool->waitWorkers();

        // Get results
        file_put_contents('AjaxThreadCount', count($scrapper_pool->getThreads())); //
        foreach($scrapper_pool->getThreads() as $worker) {
            echo($scrapper_pool->getThreadResult($worker));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is $scrapper_pool->getThreadResult($worker) printable? Does the request exceed your php max exécution time or thread number? Did you try to change your code as follows? http://opensource.byjg.com/php/phpthread.html

Comment: @JoelCrypto It doesn't exceed the execution time, I checked that by printing an echo at the end of execution.

Comment: I'm no expert in PHP Threads, so I can't give you a definitive answer, but chasing through that ByJG library, it seems like it uses `pcntl_fork` to handle your thread. Depends if you're using Apache/Nginx/mod-php/PHP-fpm/etc how threading is handled. But my guess is, by default, a separate thread won't output to the parent thread without something to coordinate and check the thread's output.

Answer (score 0):

### Important Apache webserver information

Try to run `AjaxThread.php` through command line and see if it works with (`exit()` in `ForkHandler.php`). Because you do an ajax request I suppose you run this through an apache webserver. In this case the `exit()` does not work, you should use instead:

```php
posix_kill(getmypid(), SIGKILL);
```

Comment: Unfortunately not all hosting support parallel extension, so I have to stick with what I have now.
You are right, it seems the issue is with `exit()` function, I am wondering why the threads cause the main thread to act like is exiting.

Comment: See my updated answer. I suppose you run an apache webserver. In this case, the exit causes problems. You should use `posix_kill(getmypid(), SIGKILL)` instead of `exit()`. You can also test `AjaxThread.php` through cli to see if it makes a difference. It makes a difference in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


    use \ByJG\PHPThread\ThreadPool as ScrapperPool;

    try {
        $scrapper_pool = new ScrapperPool();
        for($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
                $rfc_scrapper = new ScrapperThread($i);
                $scrap = function(ScrapperThread $instance) { 
                    return $instance->scrap(); 
                };
                $scrapper_pool->queueWorker($scrap, [$rfc_scrapper]);
        }

        $scrapper_pool->startPool();
        $scrapper_pool->waitWorkers();
        $result_getThreads = $scrapper_pool->getThreads();
        // Get results
        file_put_contents('AjaxThreadCount', count($result_getThreads)); //
        if($result_getThreads){
            foreach($result_getThreads as $worker) {
                echo($scrapper_pool->getThreadResult($worker));
            }
        }else{
            echo 'Something went wrong';
        }
        
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

Change this line:

```php
for($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
```

to

```php
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
```

Comment: although `$i++` is recommended in `for` loop declarations, in this case it doesn't make a difference because the third part is executed as its own statement, so position of ++ doesn't affect anything.